# Other than synchronizer token, is there any way of protection against CSRF using http headers?

Tags: web-application, appsec, csrf

Recently I came across some websites using HTTP Header namely X-XSRF-Token and a cookie with similar name. Is it a better mitigation than using random token based security for CSRF?

Comment: If you use script triggered request, why use a cookie at all? I'd simply use the http authentication header.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you could use something like the [X-Requested-With header](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22533680/413180) - this header cannot be passed cross domain without the server opting into this with the domain in question via CORS.

[The synchronizer token pattern is still the recommended method by OWASP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19571070/413180) - one of the reasons is that there have been [vulnerabilities in the past with browser plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24692474/413180) (e.g. Flash) that have allowed headers to be set that normally can't be set in the browser via JavaScript.

So for that reason I would recommend the synchronizer token pattern over checking headers, but at the moment of writing both are equally good. You never know if there's a Flash zero-day around the corner though.