# CSRF-protection using authentication token in HTTP header?

Tags: web-application, csrf

I'm working on a web application which stores an authentication token in a cookie.

The only CSRF-protection is referrer checking.

I am considering improving this by moving the authentication token from cookies to a custom header, such as X-AuthToken.

The application is a single page application created using JavaScript.

I believe this should be a robust protection against CSRF-attacks, because if an evil site forces a users browser to do a HTTP POST, the auth header won't be included and the request will fail.

The auth token is generated on a per-session basis.

Am I right that this would offer CSRF protection or am I missing something?

Comment: This is almost the same question as this one: http://security.stackexchange.com/q/23371/41600

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer**: yes, it would be secure if correctly implemented (long enough, random, unique tokens, one per session, etc).

**Long answer**: If you decide to add a custom header to the requests sent to the server using JavaScript code, it is similar to sending an anti-CSRF value in the POST parameters (the more often used approach).

```
POST /test 
Host: www.example.com 
X-AuthToken: unique_random_value

p1=val1&p2=val2
```

or

```
POST /test 
Host: www.example.com

p1=val1&p2=val2&x-authtoken=unique_random_value
```

So it's up to you to decide which option is easier to implement, but both should work in a secure manner.

Comment: adding on that: moving the auth token from the cookies has an effect on user experience - users will not be able to stay signed in to your website... this is why authentication tokens are usually kept in cookies. This is another good reason to keep the auth token in the cookies and implement an anti CSRF token in the headers

Comment: The name may be misleading, I understand that X-AuthToken authenticates the requests, but it is not the session token, which will be stored using cookies.

Comment: For downsides to using thie request (Flash vulnerabilities), see [this answer](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/79233/98538).